# Google Sheets/Docs Menu too big - Brave Browser

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, brave

Any Google Sheets or Google Docs is displaying the Menu way too big. On Brave Browser.
How can I decrease it?

[image: Google Sheets too big - Zoom 50%]

Comment: CTRL + -(MINUS)

Comment: This would change the size of the content but not of the Menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @player0 stated you have your zoom too big (if you look at your own picture, the zoom from the spreadsheet is at 50%). If the key shortcuts don't help try finding this zoom in your browser:
[image]